# Add contextual menu button to run powershell command inside a folder

Tags: powershell

Take this previous post as example: https://superuser.com/a/701739/761937

This is the command I use. Generally I right click on the background of the folder, open a powershell prompt in the selected path and run the following command:

```
(Get-ChildItem) | ForEach {Rename-Item  $_.FullName ($_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + $_.Extension)}
```

I added an additional button when I right click on the background of the folder to automatically run the command I need. This is the content of the key:

```
powershell.exe -noexit -command "(Get-ChildItem) | ForEach {Rename-Item  $_.FullName ($_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + $_.Extension)}"
```

but I've got multiple errors. PS is localized in my language so I don't know if I can paste the error log but maybe you can check the syntax of my command and tell me if there is something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the double quotes to single quotes in your date format pattern inside ToString method.

```
$_.LastWriteTime.ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
```

Should be fine.
Your command parameter starts with double quotes and finishes at `ToString("` and the rest of the command is not processed.

Comment: thanks! it worked. I didn't notice the double quote at all

Answer (score 0):

Rename-Item accepts piped input, so no Foreach necessary. Either escape inner double quotes:

```
powershell.exe -NoP -NoE -C "(Get-ChildItem) | Rename-Item -NewName {($_.LastWriteTime.ToString(\"yyyyMMddHHmmss\") + $_.Extension)}"
```

or as WeatherForecastingRat suggested, use single quotes:

```
powershell.exe -NoP -NoE -C "(Get-ChildItem) | Rename-Item -NewName {($_.LastWriteTime.ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss') + $_.Extension)}"
```

Comment: I tried using both of your suggested method but neither work and I had errors about parameters (still localized error logs)

Comment: Silly me, forgot the `-NewName` parameter necessary when feeding from pipe